# Интеграция исходников ZedGraph в проект

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Пытаюсь использовать данный компонент в качестве части проекта чтобы исключить внешние библиотеки. Подскажите как использовать сторонние решения как часть проекта.

На данный момент я создал папку внутри проекта под названием `zedgraph` и добавил в неё все классы из аналогичной папки с исходным кодом `ZedGraph` удалив из неё все локали кроме английской и файл .csproj.

На `Панели инструментов -> Компоненты [Имя проекта]` появился элемент `ZedGraphControl`. Но любая попытка добавить его в форму выдаёт ошибку:

> Не удалось создать компонент 'ZedGraphControl'. Сообщение об ошибке:
>   "System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Не удалось найти
>   ресурсы, соответствующие указанной культуре. Проверьте правильность
>   внедрения или связывания 'ZedGraph.ZedGraph.ZedGraphLocale.resources"
>   со сборкой "[имя проекта]" во время компиляции или убедитесь что все
>   необходимые сопутствующие сборки полностью подписаны и могут быть
>   загружены.

Что я забыл сделать?

Исходный код библиотеки [здесь](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/files/zedgraph%20source/).

Comment: Ну так вы поудаляли файлы с ресурсами для текущей культуры, чего теперь хотите?

Comment: @Андрей, какие именно нужно было оставить? Я удалил только лишние локали оставив только одну. Также был удалён ZedGraph.csproj.

Comment: не совсем понятно о чем идет речь, например вот это предложение "Подскажите как использовать сторонние решения как часть проекта." ?

Comment: @FoggyFinder, использовать исходный код библиотеки как часть проекта. Не имею привычек вешать хвосты к исполняемому коду в виде внешних библиотек/пакетов. Поэтому и спрашиваю "Как?" интегрировать.

Comment: Используйте [Costura.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Costura) - `Install-Package Costura.Fody`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась правильным вызовом файла ресурсов.

```
_resourceManager = new ResourceManager("MyFirstApp.zedgraph.ZedGraphLocale", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

NuGet расширение для VS придумано для лентяев, которым трудно добавлять сторонние библиотеки руками.

Answer (score 0):

Установите библиотеку через nuget и все зависимости сами "подтянутся".

Comment: Такой вариант не устраивает, т.к. мне не нужны внешние ресурсы для проекта умещающегося в одном небольшом EXE-шнике.